# How to see current location on a custom google map using GPS

Tags: google-maps, gps, app-inventor

I've created a custom Google Map that I'm linking to a web view in App Inventor 2. But for some reason, there is no option to see your location in Google My Maps. This creates a huge problem because I want to allow the user to see where they are on the custom map.

I'm not completely opposed to using Bing Maps or something other than Google Maps if it comes down to it; my main goal is to allow the user to see their location on the map along with all the other locations I want on the map.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this or have any alternatives?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example from Google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

```
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}
```